# Discord.py Python File not running, multiple errors

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm pretty new to coding Discord bots on my Mac instead of a Windows, and ran into trouble trying to run my Python file. I run my Python files with Visual Studio Code and the Python extension by Microsoft. I click the green play icon in the top right corner, and VSC runs it in the terminal for me. This usually works on a Windows, but for some reason, I get a ton of errors when I try to run mine.

These are the errors:

```
mika@Mikas-Air python-test % /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/mika/Desktop/python-test/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mika/Desktop/python-test/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    client.run('NzU1NDAxMTE0NTU5NDQ3MDYx.X2CwHA.6fn_XQKpuAg9V5prid_W2bof9qU')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 678, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 658, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 472, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 288, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

I do not know what those errors mean, and googled them up but didn't find any useful answers.

My code in the Python file:

```
import discord 

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="e!")


client.run('My Bot Token')
```

I have a Macbook Air 2019, the OS is 10.15.7, my Python Interpreter is 3.8.5 64-bit. The Discord.py version I currently use is the latest one, Discord.py 1.5.0 and the one that includes voice support. I checked to see if I had it installed and used the `pip install discord.py` command in my terminal, and it confirmed that I had had it installed with: `Requirement already satisfied: discord.py in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.5.0)`

My code editor is Visual Studio Code

Comment: Have you tried resetting your token? And also your token is seem on the traceback, you should edit it and change your token.

Comment: @Nurqm thanks for telling me that haha. Just reset my token, same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue and here is the fix from the discord.py discord server.

```
Getting [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] on Python 3 on OS X?
Navigate to your Applications/Python 3.X/ folder and double click the Install Certificates.command to fix this.
Happy coding!
```