# Encountered an error on the SSL Certificate in python

Tags: python, discord

### Problem :

When run an error appears as in the code below.

### Purpose :

I want to make a Discord Bot, I followed the tutorial from the website, even though it's correct but why the error? not going well ?, I'm new to Python.

### My environment :

code in bot.py which I will run:

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

the output of the code from bot.py :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "D:\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1081, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "D:\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1111, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "D:\Python\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 528, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "D:\Python\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "D:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\BotDiscord\bot.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py bot dont have certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108183/discord-py-bot-dont-have-certificate)

Comment: @PacketLoss How to ?

Comment: You have the exact same error as the one in the linked question. Does the answer resolve your issue?

Comment: @PacketLoss it seems different, I've done a "pip install certifi" but there is no effect?

Comment: Try the second answer. There is also a `github` issue opened for this which has ways to resolve it as well. Seems like a well documented error. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159

Comment: the problem with this may be the same, but I don't know how to fix it [Discord.py bot dont have certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64240886/discord-py-python-file-not-running-multiple-errors)

Comment: @PacketLoss I still don't understand, what should I do?

Comment: Done, has been fixed thanks @PacketLoss